# Conditional formatting of three rows based on `Sent`, `Received` and `Distributed`

Tags: excel, date, colors, formatting, conditional-statements

I need the cells to change color based on the condition `(blank = )` of a date being recorded in the prospective cells. Placing the first date in the `Sent` column turns `RED`, to `YELLOW` in `Received` and the all three turn `GREEN` when the date is filled in the `Received` column.

Comment: Have a look at [Conditional Formatting](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Use-a-formula-to-apply-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f).

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the `Sent` column is `F`, the `Received` is `G` and the `Distributed` one is `H`. Also that these dates are filled consecutively, ie there won't be a `Received` without a `Sent` and so on. Please select the columns to which you want the formatting applied. Then HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=$F1<>""
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, red, OK, OK.

Repeat with for yellow:

```
=$G1<>""
```

and for green:

```
=$H1<>""
```

Note that if, as recommended, you have labelled your columns this will fill the labels green. If that is a problem either select a range that does not include Row1 and row references to suit, or adjust the formulae (say by wrapping in `=AND(row()<>=1, ... )` specifically to exclude Row1, or add an additional rule for Row1 only (with no formatting set), or reduce the Applies to range.

Note also that the order in which the rules are applied may be important. This can be changed in the Conditional Formatting Rules Manager (green should be above yellow and yellow above red). The rules are applied in the reverse order I am expecting the dates to be entered. So if you opt for 'no formatting' for Row1 that should be above green with `Stop If True` checked, or at the bottom.